# How do I calculate the difference between dates?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have 2 dates 1.7.2016 and 5.12.2016, and I need to calculate number of days from month with 31 day (31+31+31+4=98).

How can I get the number of days?

Comment: I have no idea how to form a formula

Comment: [how to calculate diff between two dates in excel - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&client=firefox-b-ab&ei=2uxwWsS2E6aVgAa_1KP4Dw&q=how+to+calculate+diff+between+two+dates+in+excel&oq=excel+diff+between+dates&gs_l=psy-ab.1.2.0j0i8i30k1l6.627.627.0.4278.1.1.0.0.0.0.145.145.0j1.1.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.1.144....0.KmjqsxdEytM)

Comment: I need only number of days from month who have 31 days (7, 8, 10, and 12 month) from two dates 1.7.2016 to 5.12.2016

Comment: Where does the `+4` come in?

Comment: +4 come from 12 month

Comment: so if the ending date was 15.11.2016 would you add 14 or 0 because it is in a month with only 30 days?

Comment: I have two dates : 1.7.2016 and 5.12.2016. Diference is 157 days, but i need only days from month who have 31 day. 7 month=31 day, 8 month=31 day, 10 month= 31 day and in 12 mont=4 day. In total = 98. How i can get it ?

Answer (score 4):

#### How do I calculate the difference between dates?

> Use the DATEDIF function when you want to calculate the difference between two dates. First put a start date in a cell, and an end date in another. Then type a formula like one of the following.
>
> [image]
>
> In this example, the start date is in cell D9, and the end date is in E9. The formula is in F9. The “d” returns the number of full days between the two dates.

Source [Calculate the difference between two dates - Excel](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-8235e7c9-b430-44ca-9425-46100a162f38)

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMPRODUCT to iterate through the dates and sum up the ones that fall in the months with 31 days:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(EOMONTH(ROW(INDEX(A:A,A1):INDEX(A:A,B1)),0))=31))
```

`ROW(INDEX(A:A,A1):INDEX(A:A,B1))` creates an array of the dates from the start to the finish.

`EOMONTH(...,0)` finds the last date of that month.

`DAY(...)` returns the numerical day.

`(...=31)` tests if that day is 31.  If so it resolves to TRUE otherwise FALSE.

`--` turns the TRUE/FALSE into 1/0 respectively.

`SUMPRODUCT(...)` Cause the formula to iterate through the array above testing each date in turn and adding the 1s and 0s together.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. This formula je ok but can you tel me what is (A:A in formula?

Comment: `A:A` is just a place holder, it can be any column.  It does not mater as long as it is a full column.  We are returning a row number and not a physical value.  So it does not mater which column is used.  It could be `XAA:XAA` and still work.

Comment: Remember that if this worked for you to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.